# Show button only if word count is greater than 200 in django

Tags: django, slice

I am trying to display a button only when the word count is greater than 200
For example: if a user writes a blog of more than 200 characters the button shows up that leads to the complete post. And if its less than 200 the button should not be there

I am slicing my code with

```
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id%}">Read More &rarr;</a>
```

But in the above code the button is being displayed even with blogs of less than 200 words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make an {% if post.content|length > 200 %} and put your button inside

something like this :

```
<p class="article-content">{{ post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
{% if post.content|length > 200 %}
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id%}">Read More &rarr;</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nice! can you tag my answer as accepted and close the question ?